# Type Mismatch in ocaml

Tags: recursion, ocaml

I am trying to recursively find the nth element in a list in ocaml using the following code.

```
let rec get_val x n = match x with
    [] -> -1
    | h::t -> if (n=0) then h else get_val t (n-1)
;;

print_int get_val [1; 2; 3] 1;;
```

However this code is giving me the error

```
This function has type int -> unit
It is applied to too many arguments; maybe you forgot a `;'.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your definition is asking for two separate parameters (i.e., it is curried). But you're passing a pair of parameters `(t, n - 1)`. These aren't the same thing.

To get past this problem, change the recursive call to `get_val t (n - 1)`.

You might consider raising the Not_found exception when the list is too short. That way your code will work for lists of all types.

**Update**

Now the error is in the line where you test your function. You need parentheses there as well.

(You shouldn't keep changing your code. People who come to this page later won't be able to follow the questions and answers.)

Comment: I changed the recursive call like you suggested but i am still getting an error. I have edited the original post to show the new error

Comment: You didn't change it like I suggested! :-)  Hint: parentheses are important.

Comment: Thank you. I forgot parentheses for the print_int call which was causing the too many arguments error.